# What makes a "Special folder" - a bundle in the finder

Tags: finder

I know applications are just folder bundles - I assume specifically formatted, and some metadata. I did a copy of my iPhoto Library from another disk - at first it was just another folder, then once I ran iPhoto, it became special again.

What makes a folder a bundle? and how do i restore that metadata on a disk recovery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension of the folder determines if the folder is a special folder. For example, apps have the extension `.app`, Kernel Extensions have the extensions `.kext`, etc.

Some folders, like the iPhoto Library, have extended attributes. They can be determined by running `ls -@l` in the parent directory of your folder. The attribute `com.apple.FinderInfo` stores the type of the folder.

The easiest way to copy the attributes, in my personal opinion, is to use the `ditto` Terminal command to copy the files. It works just like `cp`, except that it also ensures that extended attributes are copied.